# Insert data to JPanel inside JTable -- JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

I cant find a way to insert data to my JPanel inside my JTable.
Anyone can help me figure it out? What i'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
JTabbedPane tabProcessamentoSalarial = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
tabbedPane.addTab("Remunera\u00E7\u00F5es", null, tabProcessamentoSalarial, null);

JPanel pnlAcumulados = new JPanel();
tabProcessamentoSalarial.addTab("Acumulados", null, pnlAcumulados, null);
        pnlAcumulados.setLayout(null);

        table_1 = new JTable();
        table_1.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        table_1.setBounds(46, 36, 508, 160);
        pnlAcumulados.add(table_1);


        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(46, 36, 508, 160);
        pnlAcumulados.add(scrollPane);

        tblAcumulados = new JTable();
        tblAcumulados.setBounds(46, 36, 508, 160);
        tblAcumulados.setModel(new DefaultTableModel() {
            String[] columnNamesRui = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};

            Object[][] dataRui = {
                {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
            };
        }
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

> What i'm doing wrong?

Why did you change the code from the Swing tutorial? The tutorial code works properly, so why did you make changes to it if you don't understand what you are doing?

1. You should NOT be using a null layout.
2. Why are you NOT creating the scrollpane by using the table as a constructor?

Start again by using the example from the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables`.